# Variable name inside curly braces in Handlebars.js

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I have a helper that prepares an expression like this `{{@../../key}}.{{@../key}}.{{@key}}`. How can I execute this expression which is returned by an helper

Example Obj:

```
{
    "a": { 
        "b": { 
            "c": 1 
             }
       }
}
```

Example:
`<input name="{{testHelper arg1 arg2}}" />`

Expected Output:
`<input name="a.b.c" />`

Recieved Output:
`<input name="{{@../../key}}.{{@../key}}.{{@key}}" />`

**[Simple Example Here](https://handlebarsjs.com/playground.html#format=1&currentExample=%7B%22template%22%3A%22%7B%7B%23each%20this%7D%7D%5Cn%5Ct%7B%7B%23each%20this%7D%7D%5Cn%20%20%20%20%5Ct%7B%7B%23each%20this%7D%7D%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5Ct%7B%7B%23each%20this%7D%7D%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5Ct%5Ct%7B%7B!--%20Expected%20Output%20(Just%20for%20illustration%2C%20cannot%20use%20this%20actual%20expression%20in%20logic)%20--%7D%7D%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Expected%20output%3A%20%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5Ct%7B%7B%40..%2F..%2Fkey%7D%7D.%7B%7B%40..%2Fkey%7D%7D.%7B%7B%40key%7D%7D%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%7B!%20-------------%20%7D%7D%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Recieved%20Output%3A%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%7B!--%20Recieved%20output%20--%7D%7D%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%7Bhelper%20this%7D%7D%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%7B!%20-----------%20%7D%7D%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%7B%2Feach%7D%7D%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%7B%2Feach%7D%7D%5Cn%20%20%20%20%7B%7B%2Feach%7D%7D%5Cn%7B%7B%2Feach%7D%7D%5Cn%22%2C%22partials%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22input%22%3A%22%7B%20v1%3A%20%7B%20v2%3A%20%7B%20v3%3A%20%7B%20v4%3A%20%7B%7D%20%20%7D%20%7D%20%7D%20%7D%5Cn%22%2C%22output%22%3A%22%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Expected%20output%3A%20%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5Ctv2.v3.v4%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Recieved%20Output%3A%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%7B%40..%2F..%2Fkey%7D%7D.%7B%7B%40..%2Fkey%7D%7D.%7B%7B%40key%7D%7D%5Cn%22%2C%22preparationScript%22%3A%22Handlebars.registerHelper(%27helper%27%2C%20function(a)%20%7B%5Cn%20%20return%20%5C%22%7B%7B%40..%2F..%2Fkey%7D%7D.%7B%7B%40..%2Fkey%7D%7D.%7B%7B%40key%7D%7D%5C%22%5Cn%7D)%3B%5Cn%22%2C%22handlebarsVersion%22%3A%224.0.12%22%7D)**

Comment: What does `testHelper` do?

Comment: It prepares an expression as mentioned in the question

Comment: Is the question just how to take an arbitrary number of strings and join them with a `.`? Like, `function(...args) { return args.slice(0, -1).join('.'); }`

Comment: No, how to evaluate a Handlebars expression inside curly braces ?

Comment: It's very unclear to me what you are trying to do. I don't understand why you need to evaluate anything. If your expected output is `a.b.c`, it means you just need to join the key names.

Comment: Challenge here is, I need to traverse from bottom to top, not top to bottom. I only mentioned a small example, I have a very deep nested object, where I cannot traverse from top to bottom. I need to traverse from bottom up, upto 4-5 levels

Comment: Maybe you should share your template and data so as to help others understand. I don't understand the use-case.

Comment: Let me make question more abstract, how to evaluate an expression inside an expression ? I am not talking about lookup, in a plain way, double resolution of a variable, consider like first resolve the output of inner expression and then evaluate the outer expression

Comment: https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/expressions.html#subexpressions

Comment: Tried, nothing works !

Comment: I have edited the question with an example

Comment: Honestly, I can't understand why you would want to do this and I would strongly urge you to restructure your problem. For academic purposes, here is pseudo-solution using a recursive helper: https://jsfiddle.net/76484/xe5t408h/

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved through a recursive helper. Like this:

```js
Handlebars.registerHelper('getPath', function(meta) {
  const resolvePath = (node, path=[]) => {
    if (node._parent) {
        return resolvePath(node._parent, [node.key, ...path]);
    }
    return [node.key, ...path];
  }
  return resolvePath(meta.data)
    .filter(p => p !== undefined)
    .join('.');
});
```

See [playground](https://handlebarsjs.com/playground.html#format=1&currentExample=%7B%22template%22%3A%22%7B%7B%23each%20this%7D%7D%5Cn%5Ct%7B%7B%23each%20this%7D%7D%5Cn%20%20%20%20%5Ct%7B%7B%23each%20this%7D%7D%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5Ct%7B%7B%23each%20this%7D%7D%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5Ct%5Ct%7B%7B!--%20Expected%20Output%20(Just%20for%20illustration%2C%20cannot%20use%20this%20actual%20expression%20in%20logic)%20--%7D%7D%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Expected%20output%3A%20%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5Ct%7B%7B%40..%2F..%2Fkey%7D%7D.%7B%7B%40..%2Fkey%7D%7D.%7B%7B%40key%7D%7D%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%7B!%20-------------%20%7D%7D%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Recieved%20Output%3A%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%7B!--%20Recieved%20output%20--%7D%7D%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%7BgetPath%7D%7D%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%7B!%20-----------%20%7D%7D%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%7B%2Feach%7D%7D%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%7B%2Feach%7D%7D%5Cn%20%20%20%20%7B%7B%2Feach%7D%7D%5Cn%7B%7B%2Feach%7D%7D%5Cn%22%2C%22partials%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22input%22%3A%22%7B%20%5Cn%20%20v1%3A%20%7B%20%5Cn%20%20%20%20v2%3A%20%7B%20%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20v3%3A%20%7B%20%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20v4%3A%20%7B%7D%20%20%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%5Cn%20%20%20%20%7D%20%5Cn%20%20%7D%5Cn%7D%5Cn%22%2C%22output%22%3A%22%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Expected%20output%3A%20%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5Ctv2.v3.v4%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Recieved%20Output%3A%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20v1.v2.v3.v4%5Cn%22%2C%22preparationScript%22%3A%22Handlebars.registerHelper(%27getPath%27%2C%20function(meta)%20%7B%5Cn%20%20const%20resolvePath%20%3D%20(node%2C%20path%3D%5B%5D)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%5Ctif%20(node._parent)%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%5Ctreturn%20resolvePath(node._parent%2C%20%5Bnode.key%2C%20...path%5D)%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%7D%5Cn%20%20%20%20return%20%5Bnode.key%2C%20...path%5D%3B%5Cn%20%20%7D%5Cn%20%20return%20resolvePath(meta.data)%5Cn%20%20%5Ct.filter(p%20%3D%3E%20p%20!%3D%3D%20undefined)%5Cn%20%20%5Ct.join(%27.%27)%3B%5Cn%7D)%3B%5Cn%22%2C%22handlebarsVersion%22%3A%224.0.12%22%7D)

**Edit:** If you really just want the path to some arbitrary depth, then use this version instead.

```js
Handlebars.registerHelper('getPath', function(depth, meta) {
  const resolvePath = (depth, node, path=[]) => {
    if (node._parent && depth > 0) {
        return resolvePath(depth-1, node._parent, [node.key, ...path]);
    }
    return [node.key, ...path];
  }
  return resolvePath(depth, meta.data)
    .filter(p => p !== undefined)
    .join('.');
});
```

See [playground](https://handlebarsjs.com/playground.html#format=1&currentExample=%7B%22template%22%3A%22%7B%7B%23each%20this%7D%7D%5Cn%5Ct%7B%7B%23each%20this%7D%7D%5Cn%20%20%20%20%5Ct%7B%7B%23each%20this%7D%7D%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5Ct%7B%7B%23each%20this%7D%7D%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5Ct%5Ct%7B%7B!--%20Expected%20Output%20(Just%20for%20illustration%2C%20cannot%20use%20this%20actual%20expression%20in%20logic)%20--%7D%7D%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Expected%20output%3A%20%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5Ct%7B%7B%40..%2F..%2Fkey%7D%7D.%7B%7B%40..%2Fkey%7D%7D.%7B%7B%40key%7D%7D%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%7B!%20-------------%20%7D%7D%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Recieved%20Output%3A%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%7B!--%20Recieved%20output%20--%7D%7D%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%7BgetPath%202%7D%7D%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%7B!%20-----------%20%7D%7D%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%7B%2Feach%7D%7D%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%7B%2Feach%7D%7D%5Cn%20%20%20%20%7B%7B%2Feach%7D%7D%5Cn%7B%7B%2Feach%7D%7D%5Cn%22%2C%22partials%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22input%22%3A%22%7B%20%5Cn%20%20v1%3A%20%7B%20%5Cn%20%20%20%20v2%3A%20%7B%20%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20v3%3A%20%7B%20%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20v4%3A%20%7B%7D%20%20%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%5Cn%20%20%20%20%7D%20%5Cn%20%20%7D%5Cn%7D%5Cn%22%2C%22output%22%3A%22%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Expected%20output%3A%20%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5Ctv2.v3.v4%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Recieved%20Output%3A%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20v2.v3.v4%5Cn%22%2C%22preparationScript%22%3A%22Handlebars.registerHelper(%27getPath%27%2C%20function(depth%2C%20meta)%20%7B%5Cn%20%20const%20resolvePath%20%3D%20(depth%2C%20node%2C%20path%3D%5B%5D)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%5Ctif%20(node._parent%20%26%26%20depth%20%3E%200)%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%5Ctreturn%20resolvePath(depth-1%2C%20node._parent%2C%20%5Bnode.key%2C%20...path%5D)%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%7D%5Cn%20%20%20%20return%20%5Bnode.key%2C%20...path%5D%3B%5Cn%20%20%7D%5Cn%20%20return%20resolvePath(depth%2C%20meta.data)%5Cn%20%20%5Ct.filter(p%20%3D%3E%20p%20!%3D%3D%20undefined)%5Cn%20%20%5Ct.join(%27.%27)%3B%5Cn%7D)%3B%5Cn%22%2C%22handlebarsVersion%22%3A%224.0.12%22%7D)